# Why listing laravel routes throws me passport error

Tags: php, laravel

When I insert this command in terminal:

```
php artisan route:list
```

I receive this error in terminal:

```
In Container.php line 895:

    Target [League\Oauth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface] is not
    instantiable while building [\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\Authorizat
    ionController, Leaugue\Oauth2\Server\AuthorizationServer].
```

```
[2019-08-01 10:16:15] local.ERROR: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController, League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer]. in /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#1 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#2 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#3 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#4 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(862): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#5 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#6 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(757): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#7 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#8 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#9 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#10 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(862): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('League\\OAuth2\\S...')
#11 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#12 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(757): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#13 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('\\Laravel\\Passpo...')
#14 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('\\Laravel\\Passpo...')
#15 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('\\Laravel\\Passpo...')
#16 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(217): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('\\Laravel\\Passpo...')
#17 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(747): Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
#18 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(708): Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#19 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php(151): Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#20 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php(114): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#21 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRouteInformation(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 0)
#23 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(766): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#24 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php(87): Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Object(Closure))
#25 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php(75): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRoutes()
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->fire()
#27 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#29 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#30 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#31 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#32 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#33 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#34 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(969): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 /home/jeen/Documentos/bng_realstate_laravel/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 {main}
```

Comment: Could you paste the error log in your question, instead of posting the link to a snapshot

Comment: update my question , paste my log error

Comment: I've meant to paste the error from the terminal when running `php artisan route:list` command. Anyway, could you also paste the PHP code / class causing your errors.